# Why my Lookup Column (which is set as required) will chose a Default Value instead of rendering an empty option

Tags: 2013, development, administration, site-column, site-settings

I am working on a Team Site collection inside sharepoint 2013. now i define the following:-

1. i created a new list named "Department".
2. i added a new site column "Project Department" of type Lookup which reference the "Department" list
3. i set the Lookup column as Required and allow single select:-

[image]

now i was thinking when the render the "Project Department" site column, i will get a dropdown with empty default option, and will force the user to select a Dept. but what i get is a list of dept and the first one being selected as default :-

[image]

so can anyone adivce on this ? now if i do the same steps for creating a choice column instead of a lookup column, then i will get a drop-down list with a defualt empty selection ..

so can anyone what is the appraoch to get this fixed ?

Comment: That's just how required lookup columns work, your work around would be to make it not required and use form validation rules to prevent saving the item without selecting a value.

Comment: @EricAlexander i thought of this but setting the lookup as optional mean the "*" will not be shown beside the column ... and i have to show it ,, to make the form more user-friendly ..